# Half-close netcat connection

Tags: pipe, tcp, netcat

How can I have a netcat connection terminate the sending half of a TCP connection if its input reaches EOF?

I have a (non-standard) TCP service which reads all its input (i.e. until the client sends its FIN), and only then starts processing the data and sending back a reply. I would like to use `nc` to interact with this service. But at the moment the reply doesn't arrive at the `nc` console, and using Wireshark I can see that `nc` only terminates the sending side of the connection when it quits (e.g. because of a timeout). I found no command line option to change this behavior.

Comment: you might try `socat` as it says in the write direction it will transfer the eof then wait `-t<timeout>` seconds on the read direction.

Comment: @meuh Thanks a lot! Even though I was asking about `nc`, it might well be that your comment is as much of an answer as I can get here. So I'd welcome seing that posted as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256790/half-close-netcat-connection#comment443778_256790) by [@meuh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/119298/meuh) suggested using [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) for this purpose. Based on that I've successfully used

```
some command | socat -t30 - TCP:localhost:1234
```

To transfer data including EOF and then still receive the response.